# human activity recognition using kinect

Tags: c#, kinect

i want to get coordinates of joints in kinect, I'm using this code but it's giving error on this line  Skeleton skeleton = (from s in skeletons where s.TrackingState == SkeletonTrackingState.Tracked select s);
here's the code;

```
public void AllFramesReady(object sender, AllFramesReadyEventArgs e)
    {
System.IO.FileStream fs = new System.IO.FileStream(@"C:\Users\MUDASSIR AHMED\Downloads\kinect samples\SkeletonBasics-WPF\Coordinates.csv", FileMode.Append, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None);
            int frame = 0;
            Skeleton[] skeletons = new Skeleton[0];


       StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(fs);
        frame++;
        using (SkeletonFrame sFrame = e.OpenSkeletonFrame())
        {
            if (sFrame == null) return;

            sFrame.CopySkeletonDataTo(skeletons);
            Skeleton skeleton = (from s in skeletons where s.TrackingState == SkeletonTrackingState.Tracked select s);
            if (skeleton == null)
                return;

            if (skeleton.TrackingState == SkeletonTrackingState.Tracked)
            {
                foreach (Joint joint in skeleton.Joints)
                {
                    sw.WriteLine(joint.Position.X + "," + joint.Position.Y + "," + joint.Position.Z + ",");
                }
                //writer.Write(Environment.NewLine);
                sw.Flush();
                sw.Close();
            }
        }
    }
```

it's showing this error
error:Error 1   Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable' to 'Microsoft.Kinect.Skeleton'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)  c:\users\mudassir ahmed\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\3dcoordinateskinect\3dcoordinateskinect\MainWindow.xaml.cs    42

Answer (score 4):

The problem is on this line:

```
  Skeleton skeleton = (from s in skeletons where s.TrackingState == SkeletonTrackingState.Tracked select s);
```

The right part of this query returns a List (IEnumerable) and you are expecting an Object (Skeleton). Maybe you wanted the first element that matches your query?

```
(from s in skeletons where s.TrackingState == SkeletonTrackingState.Tracked select s).FirstOrDefault();
```

Answer (score 0):

or you canuse 'foreach' func to get the skeleton one by one same as you do for joints

```
if (skeletonFrame != null)
{
    skeletons = new Skeleton[skeletonFrame.SkeletonArrayLength];
    skeletonFrame.CopySkeletonDataTo(skeletons);
    foreach (Skeleton skele in skeletons)
    {
        // skip the skeleton if it is not being tracked
        if (skele.TrackingState != SkeletonTrackingState.Tracked)
            continue;
        ExportCSVFile(skele, skeletonFrame);

    }
}
```